# Assigning book ids to certain students on registration of a new student

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a function where I am trying to assign book ids to certain students on registration of a new student.

```
FOR book_id IN
   SELECT a.bookid
   FROM  books a
   WHERE  a.isdelete = false and published = true

LOOP
IF NOT EXISTS (select 1 from studentbooks where  bookid = book_id and  studentid = id) THEN
     INSERT INTO studentbooks(bookid, studentid) values (book_id::uuid, id );
END IF;

END LOOP;
```

I wrote something like this and it works fine for smaller set of data and under performs when we have more books to loop through. I just wanted a have a review here.

Comment: Where does `id` column come from in your code?

Comment: I am sorry its an input parameter. The id for the new student

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of extracting all `books` and execute a separate sub-query on each `FOR` loop iteration - we can select only the *books* that don't have matches in `studentbooks` table for specified *student* (presented by `id` argument) by running PostgreSQL [`LEFT JOIN`](https://www.postgresqltutorial.com/postgresql-left-join/) with specific `WHERE` clause.

Furthermore, to make it *one-shot action* - we can *insert data from query* using `INSERT INTO SELECT` statement.

The query for the whole task:

```
INSERT INTO
   studentbooks(bookid, studentid) 
   SELECT
      b.bookid, your_function_name.id 
   FROM
      books b 
      LEFT JOIN
         studentbooks sb 
         ON sb.bookid = b.bookid AND studentid = id 
   WHERE
      b.isdelete = false AND b.published = true
      AND sb.bookid is NULL;
```

replace `your_function_name` with your actual function name to refer the function's argument name.